# Choose the hash function php uses to store array

Tags: php, arrays, hash, hashmap, hashtable

As it is, in PHP every array is stored as a orderd map (hash table). Is it possible to control the hash function that is used by PHP?

Use case - very large hash that is running really slowly. On a smaller data set it was much faster but the with a larger data set, the amount of time my code is taking to run has increased dramatically, instead of the linear increase that I expected.

Comment: Not as far as I know. But if you need a custom hash table, you can always implement it as your own class.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ArrayAccess` interface and write your own class that will act like an array, but everything will be controlled by your code.

Comment: I tried this, but since custom code is PHP it even slower. The array functions of PHP are implemented in C and are pretty fast. I think I am getting too many collisions, and this is slowing the code down. Wanted to continue using the array implemented by PHP but just control the algorithm used for the hash function.

Comment: Of course if you are using native arrays they are much more faster then your own implementation. But you can try to find a way how to optimise your iterations. In this case use of ArrayAccess or Iterator can be possible. In other case you can always write your own php extension in C or in C++ and it will work much faster. Try to find, maybe there are already some.